# Typescript session error 'property does not exist on type 'Session & Partial<SessionData>'

Tags: typescript

I am new to Typescript and making an application using it. In my back-end my trying to retrieve some session data with a router.get request and express-session.

I've received type errors for an objects from "req.session". Iv'e tried creating interfaces or adjusting my code to try to create a type for the object but my knowledge is too limited to find the solution. I would like any solution to resolve the error.

I have previously created types in another endpoint like this:

```
// Login
router.post("/login", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  // Check if email exists
  db.query(selectEmail, [email], (err: Error, rows: User[]) => {
    if (err) throw err;

    // If email exists
    if (rows.length > 0) {
      if (HashPassword(password, rows[0].salt) === rows[0].password) {
        // Create session
        req.session = Object.assign(req.session, {
          userName: rows[0].user_name,
          firstName: rows[0].first_name,
          lastName: rows[0].last_name,
          email: rows[0].email,
          profilePicture: rows[0].profile_picture,
        });

        console.log(req.session);
        res.send("Login successful");
        // Else incorrect password
      } else {
        res.send("Incorrect password");
      }
      // Else email does not exist
    } else {
      res.send("Email does not exist");
    }
  });
});
```

Perhaps there's a method that involves my `Object.assign`

Heres the exact error message I receive "Property 'email' does not exist on type 'Session & Partial'.ts(2339)", this goes for al of `req.sessions` properties ive used.

Note that my session configuration is in a different file and hasnt been imported as I have never needed to in plain JS. If you need to for Typescript this would be an obvious fix.

Heres my session config:

```
import express from "express";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import crypto from "crypto";
import session from "express-session";

const app = express();
app.use(cookieParser());

const secret = crypto.randomBytes(256).toString("hex");

// Session setup
app.use(session({
    name: "user_id",
    secret: process.env.SECRET || secret,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, // Max age one day
      sameSite: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? 'none' : 'lax',  
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
    },
  })
);

module.exports = app;
```

Heres the request in endpoint:

```
// Get user data
router.get("/login/user", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  // If user is logged in, send logged in data
  if (req.session.email) {
    res.send({
      loggedIn: true,
      firstName: req.session.firstName,
      lastName: req.session.lastName,
      profilePicture: req.session.profilePicture,
    });
  }

  // Else user is not logged in
  else {
    res.send({ loggedIn: false });
  }
});
```

Comment: Where does `request.session` come from? Did you install a package that includes that, or is that a property you added yourself?

Comment: Its from express-session. You can see ive used it in the file under "Heres my session config:" and then req is from body parser I believe. Both of these are installed the session sets up correctly I just have a Type error the code itself works as intended.